# Octal to sign in string from array

Tags: php, string, octal

I want to convert octal sign like `\46` to normal sign like `&`.
The problem is that the input is created with `preg_match_all()`, put into an array and then retrieved.

If I'd manually input the `\46` octal notation into variable with double quotes, like
`$input="\046";`
then PHP would convert it nicely.

But when I have it into an array from `preg_match_all()`, it returns it unconverted.

I want to convert it because I want to query database (mysql) that have records with "&" sign as ampersand.

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?

Comment: @carlos Hmmm... for others to edit.:)

Comment: Yup, but I'd say that it's not the best option for the regular type of question "how do i do this?" and respective answers as it does not awards reputation points. Anyway, I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stripcslashes()`

From the [stripcslashes documentation](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php):

> `string stripcslashes ( string $str )`
>   Returns a string with backslashes
>   stripped off.
>   Recognizes C-like \n,
>   \r ..., octal and hexadecimal
>   representation.

```
<?php
$a = 'a \046 b \075 c';
$b = stripcslashes($a);
echo "$a ==> $b";
?>

outputs: a \046 b \075 c ==> a & b = c
```

Answer (score 2):

there's an interesting replace trick (or rather hack)

```
$a = 'a \046 b \075 c';
echo preg_replace('~\\\\(0\d\d)~e', '"\\\\$1"', $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly elegant, but you can `eval` the string. Of course, this will eval anything else in the string too, but maybe that is what you want. If you want to avoid evaling variables you should replace $ with \$ first.

```
<?php

// The string
$a='test a \046 b';

// Output "test a \046 b"
echo "$a\n";

// Convert \046 to &
eval("\$c=\"$a\";");

// Output "test a & b"
echo "$c\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but when i have it in array from preg match all, it return it unconverted.

Try:

```
$tmp=implode('', $array_from_pregmatch);
$input="$tmp";
```