# PHP Double quoted strings escaped characters

Tags: php, string

There are two parts in the php [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) that don't make since with regards to escaping certain things:

> \[0-7]{1,3}   the sequence of characters matching the regular
>   expression is a character in octal notation
>
> \x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}     the sequence of characters matching the regular
>   expression is a character in hexadecimal notation

How exactly does this work. The documentation doesn't offer any examples. Can someone provide some for better understanding?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are confused about?

Comment: The octal escape `"\102"` represents the letter `B`, and hex `"\x46"` becomes an `F`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Octal to sign in string from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778440/octal-to-sign-in-string-from-array)

Comment: In plain old English it decodes as "*a character in octal notation is a backslash followed by 1 to 3 octal digits (between 0 and 7)*" and "*a character in hexadecimal notation is a backslash followed by an 'x' followed by 1 or 2 hexadecimal digits (0 to 9 or a to f or A to F)*"

Answer (score 0):

In many programming languages, including PHP, escape sequences like these are used to represent characters by specifying their numeric byte value in either octal or hexadecimal. For example, the character A has numeric value 65, which is 101 in octal and 41 in hexadecimal, so in PHP the strings `"A"`, `"\101"`, and `"\x41"` are all equal to one another. This is often used to represent characters that cannot be typed on a keyboard or to directly encode raw byte data into a string literal.